# what will be the integral of the following complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

the integral of the complex function---Im(z^2) over a triangle with vertices 0,1,i .

How do the vertices playing an important role?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that the path is closed and the integrand is holomorphic. Have you seen the Cauchy integral theorem?